# pgadmin with kerberos authentication - authentication failed

Tags: kerberos, pgadmin

I have followed the pgadmin instructions on setting up pgadmin web console with Kerberos authentication, but am unable to get the authentication working. The same server uses kerberos authentication for postgres access, which works.

I have a database server that hosts postgresql and the pgadmin web server. There are two service principals defined, one for each. These are:

- pgadmin/db001.algobuilder.co.uk@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK
- postgres/db001.algobuilder.co.uk@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK

I have generated two keytabs on the server. The contents look correct:

```
[jlcash@db001 web]$ sudo ktutil
ktutil:  read_kt /mnt/data/pgsql/data/pg.keytab
ktutil:  read_kt /usr/pgadmin4/web/pgadmin.keytab
ktutil:  list
slot KVNO Principal
---- ---- ---------------------------------------------------------------------
   1    6 postgres/db001.algobuilder.co.uk@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK
   2    6 postgres/db001.algobuilder.co.uk@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK
   3    3 pgadmin/db001.algobuilder.co.uk@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK
   4    3 pgadmin/db001.algobuilder.co.uk@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK
ktutil:
```

I generate a ticket for postgres and can connnect locally and remotely, but when I try and connect to pgadmin through a web browser remotely I get a message stating

> "Kerberos authentication failed. Couldn't find Kerberos ticket."

The remote server in both the psql and pgadmin test is the same, and is connected to the ipa domain with a valid ticket.

```
[jlcash@dev001 keyrings]$ kinit jlcash
Password for jlcash@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK: [jlcash@dev001 keyrings]$ klist Ticket cache: KCM:1419800001:47127 Default principal: jlcash@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK
    
Valid starting     Expires            Service principal 28/11/21 20:12:52  29/11/21 20:12:46  krbtgt/ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK [jlcash@dev001 keyrings]$
```

I have verified that the kerberos tickets for the user and service can be retrieved from the server.

```
[jlcash@dev001 ~]$ kinit jlcash -S host/db001.algobuilder.co.uk@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK
Password for jlcash@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK:
[jlcash@dev001 ~]$ kinit jlcash -S postgres/db001.algobuilder.co.uk@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK
Password for jlcash@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK:
[jlcash@dev001 ~]$ kinit jlcash -S pgadmin/db001.algobuilder.co.uk@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK
Password for jlcash@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK:
[jlcash@dev001 ~]$ klist
Ticket cache: KCM:1419800001:47127
Default principal: jlcash@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK

Valid starting     Expires            Service principal
29/11/21 13:00:20  30/11/21 13:00:14  pgadmin/db001.algobuilder.co.uk@ALGOBUILDER.CO.UK
[jlcash@dev001 ~]$
```

I have tested everything that I can think of but cannot identify the issue. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Fixed. The service principal should be HTTP. I had used pgadmin as I wanted to keep separate from other web services on the server.